# Turning a Rails AssociationRelation into a CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models

Say I have these classes:

```
class Zoo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :animals
end

class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base;
  belongs_to :zoo
end

class Lion < Animal; end
class Tiger < Animal; end
```

I can easily do `a_zoo.animals` but moreover `a_zoo.animals << a_lion_or_a_tiger`.

What I want to do is directly enable the `lions` and `tigers` method for a zoo.

I can easily do the retrieving:

```
def lions
  animals.where(type: 'Lion')
end
# analogous for the tiger, can be generalized with metaprogramming
# but right now there's no need to
```

but I'm having a hard time with the modifications. That is, `a_zoo.lions` returns an `AssociationRelation` while `a_zoo.animals` returns a `CollectionProxy`, which is updatable as far as I'm getting this.

What can I do to have all the functionality of `a_zoo.animals` transferred to `a_zoo.lions` and `a_zoo.tigers`?

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for `has_many :lions, through :animals`, take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Also, given that Animal can be of different types you should check out polymorphic associations.

Comment: Is that a solution? I knew of `has_many :through`, but I wasn't using it since I didn't think it could be applied to **generalizations**.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by generalizations but that's how I handle similar cases.

Comment: A generalization is practically a superclass. `Animal` is a generalization of `Lion`, which is a **specialization** of an `Animal` itself. I'm not sure adding a `has_many :through` association is the way to go when an association with the parent model is already there.